# Excel VBA allowing me to delete rows based on both formatting and empty

Tags: excel, filter, delete-row, conditional-formatting, vba

I am looking to delete all empty rows in my spreadsheet that aren't directly next to a coloured green square. For example:

What I have is this:

```
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
Empty
Empty
Empty
Green
Empty
Empty
Empty
Green
```

I am looking to get this:

```
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
Green
Empty
```

(and so on)

My spreadsheet is thousands of rows long - if I went through it all, deleting the whole row manually if I didn't want it, I would be here a very long time!

I have tried the filtering, but my excel skills are basic and all I can get is either all coloured, or all blank...

I looked up some VBA - I feel like this will do something similar, but as I don't know any VBA I don't know how I would change it to fit my needs.

```
Sub RemoveEveryOtherRow()
    Dim rowNo, rowStart, rowFinish, rowStep As Long
    Dim rng2Delete As Range

    rowStep = 2
    rowStart = Application.Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row
    rowFinish = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For rowNo = rowStart To rowFinish Step rowStep
        If Not rng2Delete Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2Delete = Application.Union(rng2Delete, _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNo, 1))
        Else
            Set rng2Delete = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNo, 1)
        End If
    Next
    If Not rng2Delete Is Nothing Then
        rng2Delete.EntireRow.Delete
        ' Hide every other row
        'rng2Delete.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't `green empty empty green` count too? Both empty cells are next to a green square...

Comment: I don't think there are formula's that can achieve this. However VBA (visual basic for applications) should be able to do so. Have a look at the tag: [excel-vba]

Comment: Formulas do not delete rows. You might be able to reproduce the column of data in another column with a formula but to repair the original you would need VBA. [edit] If by 'green square' you mean a green back filled cell then no, no formula is going to do this.

Comment: @DirkReichel - Thanks for pointing that out. I would like just the blank row following the green one to remain.

Comment: @Luuklag - VBA, this is going to be a whole new world for me!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code, it works properly for me:

```
Sub RemoveEveryOtherRow()
    Dim rowNo, rowStart, rowFinish, rowStep As Long
    Dim rng2Delete As Range

    rowStart = 1
    rowFinish = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


    While rowNo < rowFinish
         rowNo = rowNo + 1
         Range("A" & rowNo).Select
         Range("A" & rowNo).Activate
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell.Interior.Color <> 5287936 Then
            If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color <> 5287936 Then
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
                rowNo = rowNo - 1
                rowFinish = rowFinish - 1
            End If
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Here, the number 5287936 represents "Green" colour in Excel. And I'm assuming when you said

> coloured green square

you mean a cell with the background colour as green (5287936). I have just checked column A for empty cells, you may suitably modify the code for empty rows.